# How to display the name of a US State when using Plotly's Chloropleth Maps?

Tags: python, plotly

I created a Heatmap over the all the states in the USA, using Plotly's chloropleth maps. After extensively searching through the documentation, I couldn't find an argument to make it display the name of the States. Does anyone know how to do it, or a workaround for how to do it?

```
scl = [[0.0, 'rgb(242,240,247)'],[0.2, 'rgb(218,218,235)'],[0.4, 'rgb(188,189,220)'],\
            [0.6, 'rgb(158,154,200)'],[0.8, 'rgb(117,107,177)'],[1.0, 'rgb(84,39,143)']]


data = [ dict(
        type='choropleth',
        colorscale = scl,
        autocolorscale = False,
        locations = df['code'],
        z = df['new_old_ratio'].astype(float),
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        marker = dict(
            line = dict (
                color = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                width = 2
            ) ),
        colorbar = dict(
            title = "New/Old Ratio")
        ) ]

layout = dict(
        title = 'New Title to Old Title Ratio',
        geo = dict(
            scope='usa',
            projection=dict( type='albers usa' ),
            showlakes = True,
            lakecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'),
             )

fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )
py.iplot( fig, filename='d3-cloropleth-map' )
```

[This is the resultant map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWS9P.png)

EDIT : Added code and the Resultant plot. I want to clarify that I want to the see the names of the states ON the map at all times.

Comment: please Consider adding a sample or all your code for us to be able to test and see where the problem is. Plus you have an example here that dipslay the names when going over. https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/

Comment: @Alexis I have edited it to include my code and put in a link for the result. As mentioned in my query, I have already gone through the documentation in the link you provided. I didn't find anything of much help. I was hoping that the community might have an answer or workaround :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the code you have in the example of plotly. As you can see, there is an option called 'text' in the data wich correspond to the text you return when going over a state. In your code you don't do it.
so you need to add `df['text'] = df['states']` and then in data `text = df['text']`

**EDIT**
However, the question is about displaying all the names all the time. After a lot of research in plotly, the only thing i've found is to get the longitude and latitude of every state(center of state) and display them in [a Choropleth map with a geoscatter](https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-inset-map) with `text = df['text'],mode ="text"` I can't see another way to do it. But you'll need the coordinates wich you don't have at this point..sorry.

you can look to [this](https://python-graph-gallery.com/292-choropleth-map-with-folium/) if you really want the names on the map

Comment: I did what you suggested but I still can't see the name of the states on the heatmap. I have the names of the states in a column called  `states` so I put `df['text'] = df['states']`, but the map remained the same. I can see the states when I hover over the map, but not explicitly.

Comment: you want to put then names ON the map at all time?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry if the question didn't communicate that correctly. Is it possible?

Comment: sorry i couldn't help more. Be sure that if there is an update of plotly wich allow that i ll update the answer

Answer (score 3):

Responding on a old thread.

appending add_scattergo helped me solve exactly same issue.

```
fig.add_scattergeo(
    locations=data_state['state_code'],    ###codes for states,
    locationmode='USA-states',
    text=data_state['state_code'],`
    mode='text')
```