# R: How to display US State names ON a Plotly Chloropleth Map at all times?

Tags: r, plotly, label, maps, choropleth

I've created a very simple U.S. map using plotly's plot_geo() function and would like to add a permanent display of the labels to the states.  I have spent at least half of my day scouring Stack Overflow, Plotly documentation and even Stack Exchange GIS, and the closest solution I have found is this question, [How to display the name of a US State when using Plotly's Chloropleth Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384429/how-to-display-the-name-of-a-us-state-when-using-plotlys-chloropleth-maps), but the solutions discussed are for Python, not R.

It sounds like I need to access the ploty built-in center lat and long points for each state and add text or annotation text to those points, but I cannot find how to access the plotly built-in center lat and long points.  Am I even on the right track?  or is there another way to do this?

My current code:

```
#In R (not Python)
state_ISO <- c("US-AL", "US-AK", "US-AZ", "US-AR", "US-CA", "US-CO", "US-CT", "US-DE", "US-FL", "US-GA", "US-HI", "US-ID", "US-IL", "US-IN", "US-IA", "US-KS", "US-KY", "US-LA", "US-ME", "US-MD", "US-MA", "US-MI", "US-MN", "US-MS", "US-MO", "US-MT", "US-NE", "US-NV", "US-NH", "US-NJ", "US-NM", "US-NY", "US-NC", "US-ND", "US-OH", "US-OK", "US-OR", "US-PA", "US-RI", "US-SC", "US-SD", "US-TN", "US-TX", "US-UT", "US-VT", "US-VA", "US-WA", "US-WV", "US-WI", "US-WY", "US-DC")
state_ISO2 <- c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY", "DC")
sate_name <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming", "District of Columbia")
state_name_lower <- c("alabama", "alaska", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "florida", "georgia", "hawaii", "idaho", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", "louisiana", "maine", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", "montana", "nebraska", "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", "new mexico", "new york", "north carolina", "north dakota", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", "pennsylvania", "rhode island", "south carolina", "south dakota", "tennessee", "texas", "utah", "vermont", "virginia", "washington", "west virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming", "district of columbia")
type <- c("state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "district")
regions_census_main <- c("South", "West", "West", "South", "West", "West", "Northeast", "South", "South", "South", "West", "West", "Midwest", "Midwest", "Midwest", "Midwest", "South", "South", "Northeast", "South", "Northeast", "Midwest", "Midwest", "South", "Midwest", "West", "Midwest", "West", "Northeast", "Northeast", "West", "Northeast", "South", "Midwest", "Midwest", "South", "West", "Northeast", "Northeast", "South", "Midwest", "South", "South", "West", "Northeast", "South", "West", "South", "Midwest", "West", "South")
regions_census_main_value <- c(3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3)
center_latitude <- c(32.7794, 64.0685, 34.2744, 34.8938, 37.1841, 38.9972, 41.6219, 38.9896, 28.6305, 32.6415, 20.2927, 44.3509, 40.0417, 39.8942, 42.0751, 38.4937, 37.5347, 31.0689, 45.3695, 39.0550, 42.2596, 44.3467, 46.2807, 32.7364, 38.3566, 47.0527, 41.5378, 39.3289, 43.6805, 40.1907, 34.4071, 42.9538,, 35.5557, 47.4501, 40.2862, 35.5889, 43.9336, 40.8781, 41.6762, 33.9169, 44.4443, 35.8580, 31.4757, 39.3055, 44.0687, 37.5215, 47.3826, 38.6409,, 44.6243, 42.9957, 38.9101)
center_longitude <- c(-86.8287, -152.2782, -111.6602, -92.4426, -119.4696, -105.5478, -72.7273, -75.5050, -82.4497, -83.4426, -156.3737, -114.6130, -89.1965, -86.2816, -93.4960, -98.3804, -85.3021, -91.9968, -69.2428, -76.7909, -71.8083, -85.4102, -94.3053, -89.6678, -92.4580, -109.6333, -99.7951, -116.6312, -71.5811, -74.6728, -106.1126, -75.5268, -79.3877, -100.4659, -82.7937, -97.4943, -120.5583, -77.7996, -71.5562, -80.8964, -100.2263, -86.3505, -99.3312, -111.6703, -72.6658, -78.8537, -120.4472, -80.6227, -89.9941, -107.5512, -77.0147)

dataus <- as.data.frame(cbind(sate_ISO, sate_ISO2, state_name, state_name_lower, type,
regions_census_main, regions_census_main_value,
center_latitude, center_longitude), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = TRUE,
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

plot_geo(dataus, locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~regions_census_main_value, locations = ~state_ISO2,
    color = ~regions_census_main_value, colors = 'Blues'
  ) %>%
  colorbar(title = "Regions") %>%
  layout(
    title = 'United States by Regions',
    geo = g
  )
```

So far, my code is almost identical to the Plotly documentation (https://plotly.com/r/choropleth-maps/ - Section "Customize choropleth chart").

**EDIT:** Further on in their documentation (Section "Choropleth Inset Map") it looks like you can add permanent text by tacking on an `add_text()` argument.  I've added center lat and long to the data code above and modified the Plotly `add_text()` code to meet my situation.

```
add_text(
    x = ~center_longitude, 
    y = ~center_latitude, 
    text = ~state_name, 
    showlegend = False,
  )
```

Unfortunately, this does not produce anything different from the code above, AND I now receive a warning message:

```
Warning Message: 
'choropleth' objects don't have these attributes: 'x', 'y', 'mode'
Valid attributes include:
'type', 'visible', 'legendgroup', 'name', 'uid', 'ids', 'customdata', 'meta', 'selectedpoints', 'hoverlabel', 'stream', 'transforms', 'uirevision', 'locations', 'locationmode', 'z', 'geojson', 'featureidkey', 'text', 'hovertext', 'marker', 'selected', 'unselected', 'hoverinfo', 'hovertemplate', 'showlegend', 'zauto', 'zmin', 'zmax', 'zmid', 'colorscale', 'autocolorscale', 'reversescale', 'showscale', 'colorbar', 'coloraxis', 'geo', 'idssrc', 'customdatasrc', 'metasrc', 'locationssrc', 'zsrc', 'textsrc', 'hovertextsrc', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', '_isNestedKey', '_isSimpleKey', '_isGraticule', '_bbox'
```

Alternatively, the solution might be in an option that makes the designated hover/interactive text static. By adding `text = ~state_name` to the `add_trace()`, I can tell it what to display as the hover/interactive text (similar example found in https://plotly.com/r/choropleth-maps/).  Does there happen to be an option to make that text static instead of dynamic?

Comment: Does this one help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181278/adding-labels-to-plotly-map-created-using-plot-geo/68278621#68278621

Comment: Thanks, but I did see that post already.  The answer there involved using the tmap package which leads to some less than optimal graphical features, including displaying Alaska and Hawaii on top of Mexico.  I'm really searching for a way to do this within the plotly system.

Comment: Ok gotcha. That was a bountied question and the general sentiment (in my opinion) was that this simply is not (reasonably) possible (using plotly) in R at this time. That being said, I'd be very happy to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to add permanent labels.  The solution isn't perfect, but it does do what I asked in the post above.

Using the same data coded in the post, I had to change from using `plot_geo()` to the original `plot_ly()`, then add 2 `add_trace()` functions, one with type set to "choropleth" and the other with type set to "scattergeo".  It is the "scattergeo" trace that allows you to add the labels that you want.

```
plot_ly(dataus2, type = "choropleth", locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
    layout(geo = g, title = "United States by Census Major Regions") %>%
    add_trace(type = "choropleth", 
              z = ~regions_census_main_value, locations = ~state_ISO2,
              color = ~regions_census_main_value, autocolorscale = FALSE,
              colorscale = 'Blues', showscale = FALSE,
              text = ~state_name)  %>%
    colorbar(title = "Regions") %>%
    add_trace(type = 'scattergeo',
              locations = ~state_ISO2, text = ~state_ISO2, 
              mode = "text", 
              textfont = list(color=rgb(0,0,0), size = 12),
              showlegend = FALSE)
```

Unfortunately, it does not use the same color range of Blues as plot_geo does, and the colorscale is somehow inverted, but it is possible to add state labels to ploty_ly maps.

Note that I chose to use the state codes instead of full state names, the plot_ly automatic positioning of labels made the use of the full state names a bit messy on smaller states.

If you want to expand the permanent text displayed, replace the `text = ~state_ISO2` with something like `text = paste0(dataus2$state_ISO2, "\n", dataus2$regions_census_main_value)`. (I picked up that tip from an answer by @Skaqqs [Adding labels to plotly map created using plot_geo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181278/adding-labels-to-plotly-map-created-using-plot-geo/68278621#68278621). ) FYI, "\n" is the regex code for "newline".

For examples of how to apply this to a world map, see [plotly choropleth map: display country names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548781/plotly-choropleth-map-display-country-names?rq=1)

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Comment: @Skaqqs Very welcome! To test out its versatility, I also did a test case using the example/situation from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181278/adding-labels-to-plotly-map-created-using-plot-geo/68278621#68278621 that you referred to.  It does work.  But if the `locationmode` hasn't been set in the main `plot_ly()` function then you'll need to set it in all `add_trace()` functions.